# Create condition for dateRange with another associated fields in Laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a sales filtering page where the user can set the dateRange and if they want they can also set the currency and the customer's name as part of the filter.

[image]

```php
public function filterSale(Request $request)
{
    $customer = \DB::table('companies')->where('category', '=', 'customer')->pluck('comp_name', 'id')->all();
    $currencies = \DB::table('currencies')->orderBy('default', 'desc')->pluck('acronym', 'id')->all();

    $currency = $request['currency_id'];
    $company = $request['company_id'];

    if ($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '' || $request['currency_id'] != ''
        || $request['company_id'] != '') {
        $sales = Sales::where('publish', '=', 1)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
            ->where('currency_id', '=', $currency)
            ->where('company_id', '=', $company)
            ->get();

        return view('reports.salesReport', compact('sales', $sales))
            ->with('currency', $currency)
            ->with('company', $company)
            ->with('customer', $customer)
            ->with('currencies', $currencies);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that if the user sets the dateRage and leave the currency and customer empty, the data should display all regardless of their currency and which customer it belong to.

OR Customer + datetrage OR currency + dateRange OR currency + customer + daterage.

how can I achieve that?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Just to double check, you only want to apply the where clause if the user has set it? Is this the same for the dates as well i.e. if they don't set the dates but they do set the currency then it will only find `sales` with that currency or do the dates always need to be set?

Comment: yes the date need always to set.

Comment: if you're checking or in condition you might wanna add that into filter query also like  `orWhereBetween`

Comment: not working. Should I create separate conditions like if dateRange only / if dateRange + customer/ if dateRange + company or dateRange + customer + company ? or is there a better approach?

Comment: If no dates are provided do you still want to return `$customer` and `$currencies`?

Comment: yes @RossWilson, because the $customer and $currencies is for dropdown. so that the user can still do another search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

The first would be to if wrap your conditions in if statements:

```php
if ($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '') {
    $salesQuery = Sales::where('publish', 1)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date]);

    if ($request->input('current_id')) {
        $salesQuery->where('currency_id', $request->input('currency_id'));
    }

    if ($request->input('company_id')) {
        $salesQuery->where('company_id', $request->input('company_id'));
    }

    $sales = $salesQuery->get();

}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses):

```php
if ($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '') {
    $sales = Sales::where('publish', 1)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date])
        ->when($request->input('current_id'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('currency_id', $request->input('currency_id'));
        })
        ->when($request->input('company_id'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('company_id', $request->input('company_id'));
        })
        ->get();
}
```

---

Lastly, change your return statement to only use `compact()` so that it won't throw an error if the dates aren't included which will mean your whole controller method would look something like:

```php
public function filterSale(Request $request)
{
    $customer = \DB::table('companies')->where('category','customer')->pluck('comp_name', 'id');
    $currencies = \DB::table('currencies')->orderBy('default', 'desc')->pluck('acronym', 'id');

    if ($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '') {

        $sales = Sales::where('publish', 1)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date])
            ->when($request->input('current_id'), function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('currency_id', $request->input('currency_id'));
            })
            ->when($request->input('company_id'), function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('company_id', $request->input('company_id'));
            })
            ->get();

    }

    return view('reports.salesReport', compact('sales', 'currency', 'company', 'customer', 'currencies'));
}
```

**NB** You don't need to call `all()` after `pluck()`.

Comment: Thanks @RoseWilson, Here's the what happen to my tests, 
if I filter the date only, nothing showup.

if I filter the date with customer, it works.

if I filter the date with currency, it works.

if I filter the date with currency and customer, it works. I test in both first and second suggested IF statements

Comment: @lito I've updated my answer to use `input` instead of `has` e.g. `$request->input('current_id')`. Does it work now?

Comment: @RoseWilson it works now. when should I use the has() then?

Comment: @Lito You would use `has` to check if a specific key is present in the request.  At one point `has()` use to behave differently to `exists` but now it doesn't. Before, it would check if there is a specific key present and if the value for that key wasn't empty. I'm not sure which version brought this change though.

Comment: @Lito I've just checked and it looks like the change came about in 5.4. `filled()` is now the method that is used to check if a value is present and not empty.

Comment: I just tried filled() but I switch it back to input(). it has same result as HAS(). Thank you very much @RossWilson!